# Atom editor HTML snippets unavailable

Tags: atom-editor, html-editor

I'm trying to use the Atom editor on Windows machine for HTML authoring.
However, I can't make the HTML snippets work.

Regular completion of tags is working, but trying to invoke, for example, *html* snippet by pressing  *Tab* results in inserting the Tab character.

Also, the only available snippets for HTML grammar shown on *Alt+Shift+S* are *legal* and *lorem*.

Any ideas how to fix this or where to look for the problem?

Comment: Can you post your .cson file, most likely this is an issue of scoping?

Comment: @stefan sorry for a late reply, but it looks like the problem was due installing on the same machine both Atom and Visual Studio Code. Somehow, it seems, VSC interferes with the original Atom configurations.